# Is "to move from people to more abstract things" suitable in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> To move from people to more abstract things, the admiration and esteem for teachers can be extended to knowledge and practical wisdom, talent in arts, and scientific creativity. (self-made)

The context is that China has a tradition to revere teachers, but this moral idea is not restricted to teachers, actually it extends to general culture and education.

I am not sure whether "to move from people to more abstract things" makes sense to you people?

Comment: It makes sense, but you would probably make the message clearer by recasting the sentence to something like, “This admiration and esteem is not limited to just teachers and people in general, but can also be extended to knowledge and practical wisdom (etc.)”. When you start with “to move from people to more abstract things”, I am automatically expecting the next sentence to describe _your action_, as in, “To move from _A_ to _B_, we see that…”. “To move from _A_ to _B_, _C_ is…” seems disjunct somehow.

Comment: Thank you, your wording is much better, I should always choose the simpler way of expressing ideas.

Comment: The admiration and esteem afforded to teachers is but one facet of the high value the people of China put on education in general - the development of knowledge, practical wisdom, artistic talent, and scientific creativity.

Answer (score 2):

Makes sense to me as a native English speaker, but only on the assumption that the preceding words/sentence/paragraph had been talking about admiration and esteem for people (presumably teachers, in this case).